# Repeat prompt until condition is met

Tags: javascript

My goal is to repeat the prompt until the condition is met. I want user to enter a number. If number, then console.log the square root of the entered number.
If a string is entered (NaN) I want a different prompt and same process to repeat until a number is entered.
I have it working to loop back to the first prompt, but would like a different prompt to explain a number was not entered.

```
let userNumber = 0;
do {
    let userNumber = Number(prompt('Pick a number'));
    if (!Number.isNaN(userNumber)) {
        console.log(`Your number is the square root of ${userNumber * userNumber}`);
    }
} 
while (userNumber !== Number.isNaN);
alert('Sorry you entered something that is not a number.');
```

Comment: Then you'd need an `else` statement, perhaps changing a string variable that is the prompt, which could be restored when it *is* a number? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to this and what's above is what I tried. I will think about what you said and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the way you think about it and reverse the conditions. Exit the loop when you succeed instead of staying inside when you succeed.

```
let userNumber = Number.NaN;
let message = 'Pick a number';
do {
  userNumber = Number.parseInt(prompt(message));
  if (Number.isNaN(userNumber)) {
    message = 'Sorry you entered something that is not a number.';
  }
} while (Number.isNaN(userNumber));
console.log(`Your number is the square root of ${userNumber * userNumber}`);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, if I run the code I get "Your number is the square root of 0. I thought above I am supposed to hoist variable or set it to 0, but I must be missing something. https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/oNZxmWv?editors=1111

Comment: Sorry -- it's the inner `let` that is messing it up. I thought I had changed that.

Comment: @user3531040 I've updated the code, it seems to work now

Comment: I marked your solution as answer, but don't have enough points to upvote. I will get more points and come back and upvote.

Comment: @user3531040 haha don't worry about it. I didn't know you needed reputation to upvote -  that must be new. Glad it helped